# Names of quotients of affine varieties by reducible group actions

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, invariant-theory

Let $X$ be an affine variety over $\mathbb C$ and let $G$ be a reductive group (over $\mathbb C$) acting on $X$. It is well known then that the ring of invariants $\mathbb C[X]^G$ is finitely generated. See, for example, Theorem 1.24 in

[https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~mbrion/notes_luminy.pdf](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Embrion/notes_luminy.pdf)

Let $Y$ be the affine variety corresponding to the ring  $\mathbb C[X]^G$. We have a quotient morphism $X\to Y$.

**Question.** Does this type of quotient $Y$ have a standard name? What would be a good book/source which discusses this type setting?

Comment: This is a uniform categorical quotient. See Mumford's GIT, ch. 1, §2, Theorem 1.1.